# How to change styles of Material-UI Autocomplete list?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change styles of list/dropdown (not the input) of Autocomplete component in Material-UI.
I'm using material-styles for styling.

[image]

I would like this list to be more visible from the background so maybe increase the box-shadow.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way of doing this is by adjusting the `elevation` of the `Paper` component used by `Autocomplete`. The default elevation is 1. The example below uses a value of 8 by specifying that in a custom `Paper` component (`CustomPaper`) which is then provided via the `PaperComponent` prop of `Autocomplete`.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const CustomPaper = (props) => {
  return <Paper elevation={8} {...props} />;
};
export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      PaperComponent={CustomPaper}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Custom Paper in Autocomplete]

If the `elevation` prop does not give you the look you want, you can customize styles of the Paper component via the `classes` prop of `Autocomplete` as in the example below which uses a very ugly border for demonstration purposes, but you can make whatever CSS change you want to make using the same approach.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paper: {
    border: "5px solid black"
  }
});
export default function ComboBox() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Custom Paper in Autocomplete]

Comment: any ideal how to style the list in that paper ? I used popper component but It caused a major memory leak in my app. Thanks

Comment: @Connective-tissue Please create your own question so that you can fully describe your problem and show the code that you tried.

Comment: @Rayan Cogswell my question with code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637240/mui-autocomplete-combined-with-a-popper-component-is-causing-a-major-leak-when-d

Answer (score 0):

We are now able to change elevation or other default props of the paper by doing this in the theme:

```
MuiAutocomplete: {
  defaultProps: {
    slotProps: {
      paper: {
        elevation: 6
      }
    }
  }
}
```