# back drop filter is not working when styling autocomplete MUI's paper component using?

Tags: material-ui

I want to be able to style the the drop down background so when it opens the items behind it will become blurred any idea what class should it target ?

```js
  paper: {
    backdropFilter: 'blur(14px)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(104, 99, 99, 0.5)',
    '& .MuiAutocomplete-listbox': {
      '& li': { padding: 2 },
    },
  },
 
   <Autocomplete
          disabled={/*check?.length === 0*/ selected.group ? false : true}
          id='country-select-demo'
          PaperComponent={({ children }) => <Paper className={classes.paper}>{children}</Paper>}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
             
            />
          )}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MUI v5, then your Paper's API syntax [is wrong](https://mui.com/api/paper/#main-content). `className` should be `classes`. Or you can just use the `sx` prop.

```js
PaperComponent={props => (
  <Paper
    {...props}
    sx={{
      color: '#fff', 
      background: 'rgba(104, 99, 99, 0.5)',
      backdropFilter: 'blur(14px)',
    }}
  />
)}
```

[MUI v4 Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/back-drop-filter-is-not-working-when-styling-autocomplete-muis-paper-component-wxixk?file=/index.js)

Comment: Your sand box doing exactly what I want could you please show and append the code when using classes to your answer , since I am using mui v4.

Comment: Should I target root with my custom class and add backdrop filter and back ground color into it ?classes={{ root : classes.myPaperClass }} ?

Comment: @Richardson Disregard my remark about `classes` - that only applies in MUI v5. I have updated my sandbox to MUI v4.

Comment: btw this poppr implementation is will cause a general memory leak since you are putting a popper in to the dom and it's not getting garbage collected sure it works here but if deployed it will make extreme problems I am working on a solution now regarding the popper issue, one of the solutions I am trying is to use event listener to remove the popper. or use ref to reference it, but no luck as for now.

Comment: @Richardson The Popper component is part of the Autocomplete component. If there is a memory leak, it's on the library side. I wouldn't be surprised, considering Autocomplete is an experimental component in v4.

Comment: good to know, your suggestion is to migrate to mui5.

Comment: @Richardson I wasn't very subtle was I?  I definitely recommend migrating, but I understand if the codebase is too huge and cumbersome for that.

Comment: really huge and time line really small........... any idea how to style the drop down without using the popper component, or making the popper stop leaking, to achieve the same results as in your sand box ? I even tried to use portal and instead of using popper i used div but went all over the place I don't want to loose this blur effect on the menu.

Comment: I found a way in case you are interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637240/mui-autocomplete-combined-with-a-popper-component-is-causing-a-major-leak-when-d/70645818#70645818